# Extends does not enforce properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In this code:

```
function Component({
  onChange,
}: {
  onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent) => void;
}) {
  return <input onChange={onChange} />;
}

function Field<
  ComponentProps extends {
    onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent) => void;
    onBlur: (event: React.FocusEvent) => void;
  }
>({
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}: {
  component:
    | React.ComponentClass<ComponentProps>
    | React.ComponentType<ComponentProps>;
} & Omit<ComponentProps, "onChange" | "onBlur">) {
  return (
    /* this row should not throw an error but it does */
    <Component
      {...rest}
      onChange={(event) => {}}
      onBlur={(event) => {}}
    />
  );
}

export function App() {
  /* this row does not throw an error */
  return <Field component={Component} />;
}
```

The major problem is, that the passed `Component` should contain onChange and OnBlur property. But the TypeScript does not throw an error. It only works, if the Component contains additional property, then the checking works. The row `<Field component={Component} />` should throw an error but it does not.

The second problem I am not able to fix is rendering the `<Component>`. There I get an error but I don't know why.

I am using TypeScript **4.4.4** and React version **17.0.2**.

Comment: Can you share `ComponentProps` definition as well?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my response based on your comment below.

`FieldProps` is a type for a function that receives `ComponentProps` and returns a react element, and all other input props excluding `onChange` and `onBlur`.

When you provide the `component` prop to `<Field />` as the functional component definition and all other props as regular props, all those will be passed down the component inside `<Field />`.

[Complete code (stackblitz)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-d9glpl?file=index.tsx):

```js
type ComponentProps = {
  onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent) => void;
  onBlur: (event: React.FocusEvent) => void;
};

function Component(props: ComponentProps) {
  return <input {...props} />;
}

type FieldProps = {
  component: (props: ComponentProps) => React.ReactElement;
} & Omit<React.HTMLElement<HTMLInputElement>, 'onChange' | 'onBlur'>;

function Field({ component: Component, ...props }: FieldProps) {
  return (
    <Component
      {...props}
      onChange={(event) => {
        console.log('onChange...');
      }}
      onBlur={(event) => {
        console.log('onBlur...');
      }}
    />
  );
}

export function App() {
  return <Field component={Component} color="blue"/>;
}
```

If you remove the 'onChange' or 'onBlur' from `<Component />` you will get TS errors.

If you inspect the input you will notice the prop color passed down to the input inside `<Component />`.

I am not sure you are dealing only with input elements, if not you will need to customize this `React.HTMLElement<HTMLInputElement>` type.

Comment: Thank you for your example, but this is not what I need. I need to put onChange and onBlur inside the `<Field>`. The Idea is to have a component `<Field>` which you can pass a component. But the component must have onChange and onBlur. And can have other properties. At the end, if the component will have color property, the programmer will call the `<Field>` like `<Field component={Component} color="blue" />`. The programmer will not define onBlur and onChange. This actions will be defined inside the `<Field>`.

Comment: Like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69631117/enforced-properties-on-a-react-component-with-typescript/69636251#69636251

Comment: @user1173536 I have updated my response based on your comment.

Comment: Unfortunately that soultion does not work for me.